# Pax-logging-log4j2 having custom appenders in two packages

Tags: java, log4j2, ops4j

I have written plugins in a package and given them as a fragment of pax-logging-log4j2 and this works perfect. Now I want to have a another fragment having another set of appenders and did the same. Both the bundles get registered as fragments of pax-logging-log4j2 but the master(pax-logging-log4j2) is in resolved state now and the logs are not getting printed.

Could it be because Plugins.dat being in both fragments creating a conflict? Is there a requirement that there can be only Plugins.dat file?

If I am thinking in the wrong way please direct as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be Plugins.dat file conflict, because there is also a Plugins.dat in the pax-logging-log4j2.

Your log may print in the standard output or standard error log

Maybe your pax-logging-log4j2 config is wrong.